# How to build a Heatmap for each facet with its own respective scale instead of just one generic scale for all in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to create a `heatmap` that should **assign colors** based on `% vaccinated` **for each month** (for each row)

for example Comparison by colors between all states in month of Jan, then

for example Comparison by colors between all states in month of March .. .

then Apr ... Jun etc

**Issue:** Basically I would like **Each month to have its own high & low scale** & I am trying to do that with `facet` but it is assigning one common low-high scale for all the facets/months.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

file_url1 <- url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_vaccination.csv")

df_vaccination <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

df_vaccination <- df_vaccination %>%
  mutate(Updated.On = as.Date(Updated.On))
```

**Code:** I have tried

```
df_vaccination %>% 
  filter(State != "India") %>% 

  # summarise each month, state's vaccination
  mutate(month_abbr = month(Updated.On, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE),
         State = fct_reorder(State, Population, max)) %>% 
  group_by(month_abbr, State) %>% 
  summarise(monthly_ind_vaccinated = sum(Total.Individuals.Vaccinated_Dailycalc, 
                                      na.rm = TRUE),
            Population = first(Population), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  
  # get % Vaccination to State population for each month
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(prc_vaccinated_per_pop = monthly_ind_vaccinated / Population) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ungroup() %>% 

  filter(State %in% c("Delhi","Maharashtra")) %>%
  
  # group_by(month_abbr) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = State, y = month_abbr, fill = prc_vaccinated_per_pop)) +
  geom_tile() +
  
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "darkblue", labels = percent) +
    
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(month_abbr), scales = "free_y", nrow = 6) +
  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = -.02),
        strip.text = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "States with highest % Vaccination each month ?",
       caption = "created by ViSa",
       fill = "% Vaccinated each month",
       x = "", y = "")
```

**output:**

[image]

I think since the color value is based on `fill` so it is not letting different scales apply on different facets.

Is there anything like **(scales = `free_fill`)** instead of **(scales = `free_y`)** ?

data output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   month_abbr [6]
   month_abbr State     monthly_ind_vaccina~ Population prc_vaccinated_per_~
   <ord>      <fct>                    <int>      <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 Jan        Delhi                    43948   18710922              0.00235
 2 Jan        Maharash~               228424  123144223              0.00185
 3 Feb        Delhi                   322859   18710922              0.0173 
 4 Feb        Maharash~               794370  123144223              0.00645
 5 Mar        Delhi                   666628   18710922              0.0356 
 6 Mar        Maharash~              4590035  123144223              0.0373 
 7 Apr        Delhi                  1547324   18710922              0.0827 
 8 Apr        Maharash~              7942882  123144223              0.0645 
 9 May        Delhi                  1613335   18710922              0.0862 
10 May        Maharash~              4455440  123144223              0.0362 
11 Jun        Delhi                   250366   18710922              0.0134 
12 Jun        Maharash~              1777873  123144223              0.0144
```

Comment: Probably the best option in this case is to preprocess the data such that it satisfies your criteria; there are no free colour/fill scale options in ggplot2 (afaik).

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand, yes this is one possibility of doing it if I scale monthly % vaccination by sum of all states in that month or by max to get a relative number but then I will loose the correct % vaccination information for each month in legend to display. But may be then I can remap those with % monthly vaccination by geom_text. Thanks again .. will try this approach as well !!

Comment: If you want as many colour scales as you have months, you could make seperate plots and use the patchwork package to stitch them back together.

Comment: I was actually planning to include this in shiny app so I think I may give a input option to select month & compare states % vaccination month by month if I am not able to have all legends together